# a/the path of confrontation

Tags: articles

I ran into a sentence while reading an article on Reuters:

`...and put the two countries back on a path of confrontation.`

I wondered why it was *a* path of confrontation instead of *the* path of confrontation because from what I understood, it was a specific path and so it should call for the definite article. Further research on the Internet did not help as I found these:

`Cuban Foreign Minister Bruno Rodriguez said on Wednesday the United States was on a path of confrontation... (Reuters)`

`Once again, the North American government is taking on the path of confrontation with Cuba. (Telegraph)`

Does it have anything to do with the verbs used with a/the path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's one of a number of established English expressions such as:

> Path of least resistance
>   Path of peace

In short, the expression has become a name for hostile words and actions that are likely to lead to confrontation.

The choice of article, either **a** or **the** depends on the context and the intention of the writer.

If there is a single path of confrontation, it's **the path of confrontation**.

But if it's one of several possible paths of confrontation, it's **a path of confrontation.**